# The reason how does this German word work in custom dictionary

Tags: libreoffice-writer

The official help page has provided an example of German language.

https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/he/text/shared/optionen/01010400.html

> In language-dependent custom dictionaries, the field contains a known
> root word, as a model of affixation of the new word or its usage in
> compound words. For example, in a German custom dictionary, the new
> word “Litschi” (lychee) with the model word “Gummi” (gum) will result
> recognition of “Litschis” (lychees), “Litschibaum” (lychee tree),
> “Litschifrucht” (lychee fruit) etc.

Can someone provide an english example just to make it clear how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed (I am german). But you certainly know that this is to some extend a "german problem" because we have tons and tons of compound words. Everything is a compound word. Just some examples "door handle" is "Türklinke", "coffee machine" is "Kaffemaschine", "birthday cake" is "Geburtstagskuchen" and the infamous "Association for Subordinate Officials of the Main Maintenance Building of the Danube Steam Shipping Electrical Services" is "Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft". [Really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizit%C3%A4tenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft).

Now to your question.

I must say, after searching a bit, I think for English this is basically a useless feature. There are just so few and not very flexible real compound words. But here is an actual example. Take "sun" as new word, and specify "moon" as model word. Then the dictionary can deduce from "moonlight" that there also is a "sunlight". But I think in English this example almost exhausts the entire capabilities, while in a language like German you can generate a very high number of words, including all of their declination (which is really useful).

Comment: This "Answer" does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Is the word "Gummi" already in hunspell dict? If yes, with what tags?

Comment: Yes, "Gummi" is a normal well known German word, which is why it can be used ad "model word" for "Litschi" which is a less common word. All the declination and compound words for "Gummi" will be part of any normal dictionary, thus, this can be used and adapted to "Litschi", too.

Comment: ...and I gave a translation of the example in English, as best as possible, with "moonlight" and "sunlight". Not very exciting, but I think it can make the point.

Answer (score 0):

For apple (instead of lychee) some examples would be:

English: Apple tree, apple pie, apple juice, apples
German: Apfelbaum, Apfelkuchen, Apfelsaft, Äpfel

What exactly don't you understand? btw. I am German

Comment: If you add the new word “Litschi” (lychee) with the model word “Gummi” is it really working as mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean by "model word"? Interchangeable?